# mouseenter and mouseleave behaving strange

Tags: jquery, html, css

I was playing around on a fiddle trying to replicate the effect that is on the stack overflow careers home page, where when you hover on a city image, it expands.

I used jQuery `mouseenter and mouseleave` events to trigger the animation, but if you move your mouse around really fast on and off the image, it starts to resize too extremely.

heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndeb6hnt/

why is this happening?

here's the relevant jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isAnimating = false;
    $('.image-box').mouseenter(function() {
        var thisImage = $(this).children().first();
        var imageWidth = parseInt($(thisImage).css('width').replace('px', ''));
        var imageHeight = parseInt($(thisImage).css('height').replace('px', ''));

        $(this).children().first().animate({
            width: imageWidth + 50,
            height: imageHeight + 40,
            marginLeft: -25,
            marginTop: -20
        }, 200);

    }).mouseleave(function() { var thisImage = $(this).children().first();
        var imageWidth = parseInt($(thisImage).css('width').replace('px', ''));
        var imageHeight = parseInt($(thisImage).css('height').replace('px', ''));

        $(this).children().first().animate({
            width: imageWidth - 50,
            height: imageHeight - 40,
            marginLeft: 0,
            marginTop: 0
        }, 200);
    });


});
```

Comment: You need a `.stop(true)` before the `.animate()` in the chain most likely - but I didn't click on the fiddle. In the future it's best to include the relevant code in the question.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum ok I'll try the `stop` method. People shouldn't just down vote though, fiddle is a quick link...

Comment: I didn't downvote so I'm not sure I'm qualified to comment on why someone did. If I had to guess it's because of the title not being indicative. Other than that the question looks fine to me.

Comment: You probably got downvoted because you didn't post your code in your question. That should always come before any link to jsFiddle, jsbin, etc. Those sites should serve as a supplement to the code in your question -- not as the only source of it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum fair enough. Where does the `.stop(true)` go exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'd skip the jQuery since this can be done in CSS:

```css
.image-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: tomato;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-box-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
.image-box-image:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class='image-box'>
  <image class='image-box-image' src="http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, css only way! thank you for sharing, I need to start using this instead of jQuery for everything

Comment: I'm trying to run the code snippet but the image isn't resizing

Comment: Works fine for me in FF and Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm updating the answer so that it works in Safari. Hold on a sec.

Comment: OK, should be good now. Just needed the `-webkit-` for Safari.